# How to add a Java class to Kotlin project in Android 3.0?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Currently, I know more of Java than of Kotlin, so the paste-auto-translation feature is helpful. To do this, I wanted to create a dummy Java class, so that I can write java code and copy-and-paste into a Kotlin file. I right-clicked the directory where other Kotlin files are in a project for which I checked 'Kotlin Support' at its creation, and selected `New` -> `Java class`.

But it showed an error : `Unable to parse template "Class"`. What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. You could always make a blank Java file without the template dialog

Comment: I forgot that there was `File`. I created a new `File` with a name `test.java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in Android 3.0 release, In order for you to add a template go to:

**File > Settings > File and Code Templates** and click `Class`.

Add this code below and hit OK.

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

public class ${NAME} {
}
```

[image]